# Why does treating $x$ or $y$ as a constant allow partial differentiation to work?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm basing my knowledge on the Khan Academy's video I'm fond of [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfvnCHqzK54) In the video, the speaker illustrates what's going on during partial differentiation. To better see where I'm confused and where my question  lies, I'm going to explain what I gather:

- We have a function with inputs $x, y$
- We can't directly differentiate a function with respect to two inputs because the... I need a better explanation for this, but you can only do it implicitly (?) and this doesn't do the job for some reason.
- As a result, we need to see how $z$ changes if we nudge $x$ or $y$ from a given point $(a,b)$ in the input space. I like to think of it as an analogy to  Minecraft, looking down at the ground from a bird's eye view. Or some generic 3-D game. $z$ can be the player's displacement in the $z$ direction, towards the skybox in most 3D games. Suppose one looks at a player's character from a bird's eye view, and immediately right of him (some $\Delta x$) is a spring and immediately forward is a cavern. In the $z$ output space, if the player satisfies the $x$ and coordinates needed at the fixed $y$ to touch the spring, the player will jump and his $z$ displacement will find a peak. The world varies based on position in $x,y$. Hopefully my general analogy of 3D video games can apply.
- If we fix $y$, we can observe the image of the 3-d plot in the $x-z$ plane with a fixed $y$, and find the partial derivative with respect to a fixed $y$. The same applies to fixing $x$.

However, as you vary $y$, the image of $z$ as a function of $x$ varies. Taking the partial derivative renders a solution with two inputs, so if you found the partial derivative of $z$ with respect to $x$ it will have $y$ as an input and that will account for the varying $xz$ image as $y$'s fixure varies. However, what I don't understand is why treating $y$ as a constant when finding the partial derivatives of $z$ with respect to $x$ *accounts for this.* What I'm inclined to believe as an extension of one input calculus is a partial derivative will be in the form of a $2$ variables function as well and when $y$ is fixed it represents a tangent line to the $xz$ slope. What I'm also inclined to believe it's  because in $z$ with respect to $x$, $y$ will always be a constant, but it's still a bit fuzzy. But what I do know is that partial differentiation explains what a nudge of $x$ or $y$ will do to $z$ no matter what pair of points it's observed in, and I find that hard to reconcile when nudging $y$ at the very center of a sphere won't have much change in $z$ but a nudge in $y$ at an intermediary point can have a sharper change.

I hope some light can be shed on this for me. I know this question is wordy and perhaps demanding, but please do consider giving this a bite and letting me know if anything is too wordy and needs to be better explained in my illustrating my confusion.

Comment: Your post is basically incomprehensible, and it's hard to see what the title question has to do with what you've written. I'd recommend you stop looking for video game analogies, which obscure the key ideas, and just think about the mathematics. You have a real-valued function of two variables $f(x,y)$. The partial derivative with respect to $x$, $f_x(x,y)$, is also a function of two variables; so is the partial derivative with respect to $y$. What, exactly and concisely, is your question?

Comment: My question is why the process of partial differentiation: treating one variable as a constant and differentiating the other solves the confusing point I made earlier - that the image of $xz$ changes with a given set $y$ value (and vice versa for $yz$ and $x$ obviously). My other question, which I'm trying to explain clearer, is why this approach also applies to any pair of points, basically asking why there are only $2$ "global" partial derivatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Single variable calculus gives you the tools to take derivatives of functions $f(x)$ of one variable. The derivative $f^\prime(x)$ is a function which tells you for each value of $x$ how steep the function $f(x)$ is there, or in other words how much the height changes if you move a little bit away from $x$.
2. In multiple dimensions (i.e. with multiple variables), we still have this idea of steepness: at the point $(x,y)$ how much does the height change as I move in a direction?  But now we have not just one direction (left-to-right), but many (in the $x$ direction, in the $y$ direction, and so on).
3. We can actually use the tools of single variable calculus to help us find the answer to multivariable questions like these. All we have to do is find a way to transform it into a single-variable kind of question.
4. Suppose we have a function $g(x,y)$ and we want to know, at each point $(x_1, y_1)$, how much the height changes if you move in the $y$ direction. Implicitly, of course, we're moving *only* in the $y$ direction and not at all in the $x$ direction.

   One of the tools of single-variable calculus is the idea of a *limit*. We originally used it to define a single-variable derivative as a limit of a difference quotient:
   $$f^\prime(x) \equiv \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}$$
   Which means: "Pick a value of $x$. How steep is the line joining the two points $f(x)$ and $f(x+\epsilon)$ on the curve, in the limit as the step size $\epsilon$ becomes infinitely small?"

   Here, with a multivariable function $g(x,y)$, we can use this same construction. For each point $(x_1, y_1)$, we want to know how the height of the function $g$ changes at that point if you move purely in the $y$ direction. We'll call this y-directional slope function $\partial_y g$, and we can write a formula for it as a limit, where $\epsilon$ is the step size:
   $$(\partial_y g)(x,y) \equiv \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x,y+\epsilon)-g(x,y)}{\epsilon}$$
5. Here, finally, is the answer to your question. This definition of slope in the $y$ direction looks very similar to the definition of a single-variable derivative. Can we make it *exactly* like a single-variable derivative?  If we can, it will be computationally useful because currently our only method for computing partial derivatives involves computing limits—we'd like to be able to use all the single-variable algebraic shortcut tricks like the product rule and chain rule.

   Suppose I knew in advance what the value of $x$ would be— suppose, for example, I only care about the value of the partial derivative around where $x=5$.

   In this special region, the formula for the partial derivative becomes

   $$(\partial_x g)(5,y) = \frac{g(5, y+\epsilon)-g(5,y)}{\epsilon}$$
   But look! Suppose you define a new single-variable function $G_5(y)$. You compute the value of $G_5(y)$ by computing $g(5,y)$. Note that $G_5$ is a function of $y$ alone— and note that according to the difference formula definition of these derivatives, the partial derivative of $g$ at $x=5$ is the same as the **ordinary derivative of the function $G_5(y)$**:
6. The algebraic trick is to note that there's nothing special here about the value $x=5$— given any other value $x=u$, we could have defined a new single-variable function $G_u(y) \equiv g(u,y)$. Then the partial derivative of $g$ in the $y$ direction at the point $(u,y)$ is the same as the ordinary single derivative of the special function $G_u(y)$.

   The function $G_u(y)$ depends only on $y$. The value for $x=u$ is baked into its definition. Its definition is that it's equal to $g(x,y)$ with the value of $x=u$ held constant.  Hence to compute how the slope of the function $g(x,y)$ changes at each point $(x, y)$ as you move in the $y$ direction, it's the same as computing the ordinary derivative of the related function $G_x(y)$ where the value of $x$ has been baked into the definition of $G_x$, and $y$ is the only variable.

   That's how the single- and multi-variable derivatives are related, and that's why you can compute slopes in multiple dimensions by "treating the other variables as constants" — you're just computing the ordinary derivative of a single-variable function where the values of the other variables have been baked in. The reason why this produces the correct answer is because we have a limit definition of slope for the one-variable and multi-variable case, and the limit of your original multi-variable function is apparently equal to the limit of this special single-variable function.

Comment: This was wonderfully helpful and I really appreciate you taking the time to write this for me. Some bits were a bit confusing, so what I'll do is attempt to re-answer my question using your help and tell me what I need to adjust in my answer: With the bit about how arbitrary $x=5$ is, looking at each image of the $yz$ plane of a function will be the exact same regardless of what constant is taken, as it's the same concept as moving the origin up or down in a function -- it's still the same function, but viewed centered at a different point.

Comment: Like, looking at the line $y=x$ near where $y = -150$ doesn't change the fact that the line you're observing is $y=x$ just because it doesn't look the exact same as it would at $y=0$. Hopefully that makes some sense. For the other question, is $G_5 (y)$ literally just a line like $y=5$? I'm confused about what it exactly is, and how you tied that together to state that "the partial derivative of 
g
g
at 
x=5
x=5
is the same as the ordinary derivative of the function 
G
5
(y)
G5(y)"

Comment: @sangstar. If you picture a function $g(x,y)$ as a hilly surface with a different height at each point, then what we are doing is cleaving that hilly surface using a knife along $x=5$.  When we pull apart the two halves, we see that the exposed edge is a one-dimensional curve like we're used to. It has a height as a function of $y$. The partial derivative of the surface is the same as the usual derivative of this curve.

Comment: But wouldn't there be a different curve with each different slice of $x$ in that case? If there are a bunch of erratic hills and troughs on the surface, say we cut a slice with a hill around say, some $-y$ and a trough at some $+y$ and we cut a slice at $x=5$ like you said, would we not have two different curves to take the derivative of? Plus, either half shouldn't have the same curve unless the surface is symmetrical, no?

Answer (score 4):

When taking partial derivatives of some function f(x,y) we need to hold one constant to observe how it behaves in the other direction. suppose we can have some surface where the function z takes on a value of 4 at x=1, y=1. $f(x,y)= 3x^2+2xy-y^2$. We graph this as a height of 4 over the square x=1 y=1. Graph this out and it should have the rough shape of a mountain.

If you stand on the mountain facing parallel to the x axis allowing x to increase and y stays constant you would be moving forward in a straight line along the mountains shape. This slope is then the change in the $z$ or f(x,y) [which is the height of the object] in response to movement along the axis in one direction. in our case the x direction holding the y constant.

The same can be done for they y direction.